# How to share data between actors that should be cached

Tags: scala, akka

I have a "main" actor that creates many child actors.

The child actors perform work, and they all need access to data that I have to retrieve from the database.

I want to cache this data because it will be very resource intensive for each actor to be hitting the database for this data, and it doesn't change that often (I have a good strategy for cache invalidation already).

For example, my child actor will need:

1. Account
2. User
3. etc.

These objects need to be loaded from the database.

How could I load these objects, and somehow share them with all my other actors?

Would the best way be to create a shared class that has a reference to guava cache?

**Note**
I don't want a distributed cache, I think an in-memory cache will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two approaches here:

1. Give each actor a reference to the cache (given the cache is thread-safe)
2. Create more actors that facilitate access to the cache.

Approach 1 is simple but causes an actor to block whenever a cache-miss occurs, so it cannot process other messages before the cache loads or computes the required value.

Approach 2 requires more actors but gives you more flexibility. However, if you only add one other actor for accessing the cache, you are creating another bottleneck. A cache-miss will then block all other actors that are accessing the cache. You would rather have several actors for this purpose, so you can a) really access the cache concurrently, b) not block a particular actor that depends on the cache when a cache-miss occurs.

Comment: for approach #1, I could always add the cached data before I send work to the child actor, so it will always be present.

Comment: You mean when you instantiate the actor, you give it a reference to a cache object containing all the data it will ever need? So your actor will never request something from the cache that is not already cached? I think I wouldn't call it a cache then.